# delayed result in sinc upsampled signal

Tags: python, interpolation, resampling, numpy

I have implemented an infinite kernel sinc interpolation.
For some signals I notice an artifact, visible at the right end of the plot.
I am wondering: is it a bug in my code or a phenomenon usual for this method?

[image]
red: 2x upsampled signal
blue: signal expected to be an output of the interpolation
sr (each) = 1000

Comment: Sinc interpolation is very hard to implement because the computer's numerical precision is not large enough to represent very long sinc signals. Having said, that, you could simply have a bug in your code.

Comment: what's an *"infinite kernel sinc interpolation"*?  if it is what i think it sounds like, how do you add an infinite number of terms together?

Comment: and in the figure above, the alignment of the blue dots are not vertically aligned with the red dots.  (actually i am having second thoughts about that observation.)  is that your intention (since you state that the *"sr"*, i presume *"sample rate"*, is the same for both signals)?

Comment: okay, there appears to be vertical alignment of the dots.  so my first observation was incorrect.  so what appears to be happening is that your blue signal is derived from your red signal in such a way that there it starts out with no delay at left and slowly increases the delay as the blue signal moves to the right.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I mean, that i do not restrict the size of the kernel. I create time array with sampling rate of upsampled signal, apply sinc function to whole of it.

Comment: if you do not restrict the size of the kernel, how do you implement the kernel without adding up an infinite number of terms?

Comment: It is a discrete signal :)

Comment: I know, that the best way to implement it would be using convolution, but I am required to write the simplest implementation.

Comment: At this point I am quite convinced that there is a bug in my code. Thank you for help. If you wish, when I hunt it down, I could show it to you in my repository :)